# would you give me a more clear example to get it better?

Tags: meaning

Would you please show me the following in a more readily aspect?

> ...general unspecific anxiety ("diffuse anxiety") may subconsciously choose something specific to be afraid of (like spiders, for example), and they will then direct all of their previously undirected anxiety onto that external object, which they seek to avoid.

This is not a copy of my other question here [would you throw a light on the concept of the sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55020/9161). As I have updated that, but the change may have not been considered very well, so I had to ask another question of it here.

[Insects in Psychiatry](http://www.insects.org/ced2/insects_psych.html)

Comment: Which parts of the excerpt are you having trouble with? It's difficult to rephrase something in a way that will be helpful if we don't know what about the sentence is causing a problem.

Comment: Also, I can't find that sentence in the link that you provided - is it the correct link?

Comment: @ColleenV, it's from TRomano's answer to http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55020/would-you-throw-a-light-on-the-concept-of-the-sentence

Comment: It's difficult to answer questions that don't have the correct context and even more difficult to answer "explain this in a better way" questions when we don't understand why the first way wasn't helpful. Is there a reason why your request isn't in the original question? Even if you aren't able to comment you can always edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is this:

- someone is suffering from "General unspecific anxiety": that is, they're just nervous and worried all the time.
- their mind subconsciously thinks "I can't just be nervous all the time for no reason, there must be something that's making me nervous."
- their mind then fixates on a specific thing that is a possible cause of anxiety:  "I've never liked spiders.  Spiders made me nervous once or twice before.  Spiders must be why I'm nervous now."
- From then on, any time they feel anxious, they blame it on spiders.
- In order to try to feel less anxious, they go out of their way to avoid spiders.